# VBScript: Round number UP to nearest thousand

Tags: vbscript, rounding

I have numbers that I want to round **up** to the nearest thousand (unless the number is already rounded to the nearest thousand):

```
 1,000      to   1,000.00
 2,100.00   to   3,000.00
 3,500.99   to   4,000.00
 4,900      to   5,000.00
```

How can I do this?

Comment: The Excel equivalent seems to be `=-INT(-A1/1000)*1000` and the python equivalent seems to be `-(-!cost!//1000)*1000`.

Comment: And this is how its done in Oracle SQL: `ceil(COST/1000)*1000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
-Int(-[cost]/1000)*1000
```

---

*A related question here: [Field Calculator: How to round UP to the nearest thousand](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256817/field-calculator-how-to-round-up-to-the-nearest-thousand/256822?noredirect=1#comment405500_256822)*

Answer (score 0):

Here's some pseudo-code (JS) to do it. I can explain the algorithm, although do not know vbscript syntax.

First, the only digit we care about is the most-significant, or the thousand's place. So we first isolate that digit by shifting the number three places to the right.

2100 -> 2.100

Then we use a ceiling function to force the decimal to round up to the next nearest integer.

2.100 -> 3

Now we can re-shift the number three places left so it is of the original magnitude.

3 -> 3000

vbscript may or may not have a ceiling function ([here's an implementation of one](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/10/vbscript-ceil-and-floor-functions.html), and the other functions are simple mathematical operations.

```
function toNearestThousand(x) {
    return Math.ceil(x/1000)*1000;
}
```